# In Linux, how to occupy console the std out exclusively?

Tags: linux, console, serial-port

I am working on embedded Linux, only one serial port, and used to be debug console. However, I need to I/O data by serial port, too. How can I use the console, the serial port, exclusively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the appropriate argument from the kernel command line and disable any getty that may be started on it by the startup processes.

Comment: Yes. Ask someone else to do all that for you.

Comment: I didn't try this, but I agree that the solution work. So accepted.